# SQL simple GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to make a simple GROUP BY query with SQL and not use COUNT,AVG or SUM? I want to show all columns and group it with a single column.

```
SELECT * FROM [SPC].[dbo].[BoardSFC] GROUP BY boardsn
```

The query above is working on Mysql but not on SQL, is there a way to achieve this? any suggestion would be great

UPDATE: Here is my data I just need to group them by `boardsn` and get `imulti` equals to 1[image]

Comment: I am guessing your end goal is to get multiple datasources into one column?

Comment: Sorry i have just re-read the question it wasnt making sense the first few times i read it that is my fault

Comment: In SQL Server, you'll have to list all of the columns in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Basic Rule is when you are using group by `Either` you should include all columns in the group by `or` they must be in aggregate function. In your case you are selecting all the columns but only have one in group by.

Comment: what is the desired output of such query? I just can't imagine what could it be ...

Comment: Guys thanks for your response I updated my question and added the data I just need to group the data by `boardsn`

Comment: @Sarotobi but what would you like to see in the "imulti" column or "LifeCycle" for example?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev "multi" should be always 1 and "boardsn" is group

Comment: then add WHERE imulti =1  and you'll probably get single record. You can also use DISTINCT with the combination of the predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you just understand 'group data' in a different way than it is implemented in sql server. You simply want rows that have the same value together in the result and that would be ordering not grouping. So maybe what you need is:

```
SELECT *
FROM  [SPC].[dbo].[BoardSFC]
WHERE imulti = 1
ORDER BY boardsn
```

Answer (score 0):

> The query above is working on Mysql but not on SQL, is there a way to achieve this? any suggestion would be great

No, there is not. MySQL only lets you do this because it violates the various SQL standards quite egregiously.

You need to name each column you want in the result-set whenever you use `GROUP BY`. The `SELECT *` feature is only provided as a convenience when working with data interactively - in production code you should **never** use `SELECT *`.

Comment: " in production code you should never use SELECT *" the never word is not right there. "Try to avoid" it is better word. SELECT ... FROM TABLE t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE ...) works well with "*". I can give you more examples where "SELECT *" is good way to go.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Production code must never use `SELECT *` because it will mean any database-to-entity mapping code will be broken if the table schema or subquery column set ever changes. The only way to preserve this is by explicitly naming the columns the software expects to receive.

Comment: How would my example SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * ...) would broke the code? Another example, if you need an interface for some table in other database. You create VIEW and reference it as select * from another_db.schema.table and it works well.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev  The (NOT) EXISTS might be a bad example to make your point.  Because you can replace that * by 1 or any value.  It does make sense when selecting from subqueries that do have the fields typed out.  f.e. `select * from (select 1 as foo, 2 as bar) q`

Comment: Select * is bad habbit. And i agree with @Dai - And you will have serious issues if you use this in SSIS ex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TOP 1 WITH TIES combined with a ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM [SPC].[dbo].[BoardSFC] 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY boardsn ORDER BY imulti)
```

Or more explicitly, use ROW_NUMBER in a sub-query

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY boardsn ORDER BY imulti) as RN
  FROM [SPC].[dbo].[BoardSFC] 
) q
where RN = 1
```